# Why the output of IIR filter differs when the same code is run on a pc and embedded target?

Tags: c, matlab, embedded

I am implemented an IIR filter in cascaded biquad form defined by the ARM documentation, on both embedded and C code. Both the codes process the data in the same way. But the output from C differs from the output of the embedded code.
Also tried filtering the same data through MATLAB. The output is similar to C code output.So,the outputs from MATLAB and C are matching but the embedded doesn't.
The embedded code is running on ARM-cortex M33 device with a FPU extension. Is the difference due to the processors on the pc and the embedded device?

This is the C code used to filter the data.
The inputs are included from separate files which have the unprocessed data collected from the embedded device.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "arm_math.h"
#include "coeffs.c"
#include "datax.c"
#include "datay.c"
#include "dataz.c"

#define NUM_STAGES_0_3  6
#define NUM_STAGES_3_7      6
#define NUM_STAGES_7_13     8
#define NUM_STAGES_13_25    10
#define NUM_SAMPLES         1000000
#define BLOCK_SIZE      50
#define FREQ1           1
#define FREQ2           5
#define FREQ3           10
#define FREQ4           15  

//float32_t input[NUM_SAMPLES];
float32_t output[4][NUM_SAMPLES];

float32_t buf_0_3   [4*NUM_STAGES_0_3]; 
float32_t buf_3_7   [4*NUM_STAGES_3_7];
float32_t buf_7_13  [4*NUM_STAGES_7_13];
float32_t buf_13_25 [4*NUM_STAGES_13_25];

void main()
{   
    arm_biquad_casd_df1_inst_f32 S[4];
    uint32_t blockSize = BLOCK_SIZE;
    uint32_t numBlocks = NUM_SAMPLES/BLOCK_SIZE;
    uint32_t num_samples = NUM_SAMPLES;
    uint32_t i;
    
        arm_biquad_cascade_df1_init_f32(&S[0], NUM_STAGES_0_3, coeff_0_3, buf_0_3);
        arm_biquad_cascade_df1_init_f32(&S[1], NUM_STAGES_3_7, coeff_3_7, buf_3_7);
        arm_biquad_cascade_df1_init_f32(&S[2], NUM_STAGES_7_13, coeff_7_13, buf_7_13);
        arm_biquad_cascade_df1_init_f32(&S[3], NUM_STAGES_13_25, coeff_13_25, buf_13_25);
        
    for(uint32_t i=0;i<numBlocks;i++)
    {
                arm_biquad_cascade_df1_f32(&S[0], input+(i*blockSize), &output[0][i*blockSize], blockSize);
                arm_biquad_cascade_df1_f32(&S[1], input+(i*blockSize), &output[1][i*blockSize], blockSize);
                arm_biquad_cascade_df1_f32(&S[2], input+(i*blockSize), &output[2][i*blockSize], blockSize);
                arm_biquad_cascade_df1_f32(&S[3], input+(i*blockSize), &output[3][i*blockSize], blockSize);
     }                                                              
}
```

Comment: "output from C differs from the output of the embedded code" Aren't they both in C? Is this code here "the C code" or "the embedded code"? In case of the latter why do you let it return from main()?

Comment: @Lundin. This code is the "C code". The embedded code is also the same and written in C but the embedded code will be run on a microcontroller. That's what's meant by embedded code. So,could the output differ when run on arm and pc processors?

Comment: Have you considered to try only one filter/biquad and not a cascade for debugging purpose?

Comment: The info about the embedded env is a bit sparse, though, it could be also some compiler options regarding the FPU settings (fast FP vs strict IEEE-754 FP).

Comment: @Irreducible  I haven't considered it. I will compare the results from single biquad or maybe even some series of multiplications could serve the purpose. I will try to debug from the basic level.

Comment: So the distinction is code running on a PC and the _same_ code running on an embedded target - and not between "C code" and "embedded code" - which makes no sense.  The confusion you have caused there is an unnecessary distraction from your question - you should correct that in the question rather then explain "what you mean" in a comment, because no amount of explanation will make it make any sense as a statement.

Comment: Given that `arm_biquad_cascade_df1_init_f32` is an ARM CMSIS DSP library function, I presume your PC implementation is not in fact the same at all and uses some other .  In what way does it differ - it would not be surprising that the output is not identical , but is it nonetheless correct in the sense of having the desired frequency/phase response etc.  For example the CMSIS DSP might have a different gain than the PC or MATLAB implementation, but would nonetheless be "correct" from,  signal processing point of view.